# How to store an array into a session and call it in Laravel?

Tags: arrays, forms, laravel, session, controller

I have some fields in the form

```
 <form action="users/registration/new_user" method="post" class="new_user" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                 <label for="" class="dis-block">姓 <span class="text-error">※</span></label>
                  <input name="user_last_name" type="text" class="form-control" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                 <label for="" class="dis-block">名 <span class="text-error">※</span></label>
                  <input name="user_first_name"  type="text" class="form-control" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">
                 <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ch-width-100">
                      <label for="" class="dis-block">Email <span class="text-error">※</span></label>
                      <input name="user_email" type="email" class="form-control" required="required">
                 </div>
            </div>       
 </form>
```

On my controller

```
 public function postRegister(Request $request)
        {
           Session::put('user',['user_last_name'=>$request->user_last_name,'user_first_name'=>$request->user_first_name,'user_email'=>$request->user_email)]);  
           //Try echo to try it out
           echo Session::get('user'); 
        }
```

Error

```
  ErrorException in SignupController.php line 146:
   Array to string conversion
```

Now I have to do to save the array into the Session and when I need to call it can call the values by the foreach.
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
Session::put('user', [...]);
```

It works. Your error comes from

```
echo Session::get('user');
```

You are trying to 'echo' an array. Replace it with

```
dd(Session::get('user'));
// or 
print_r(Session::get('user'));
```

To use it in a foreach, you simply do

```
if ( Session::has('user')) {
    foreach(Session::get('user') as $prop) {
        echo $prop;
    }
}
```

**Update**

The user you are saving is a simple array. But it seems you actually want an object. You should change the way you save it like this:

```
$user = (object) [
    'user_last_name'=>$request->user_last_name,
    'user_first_name'=>$request->user_first_name,
    'user_email'=>$request->user_email
];

// or simply try like this
$user = (object) $request->all();

// or if you have a user Model 
$user = new User($request->all());
```

Then save it in the session

```
Session::put('user', $user);
```

Finally you can use it anywhere as an object

```
$user = Session::get('user');
echo $user->user_last_name;
```

Comment: Thank you! I have already shown out, but now I want to foreach like this
  `foreach (Session :: get ('user') as $ use)
         {{
              echo $use- user_last_name;
         }`
Then be warned, looking forward to help.

Comment: Check my update to see how to use it as an object. No foreach needed.

Answer (score 0):

As for Laravel 8, session is not a class with static methods any longer, but a simple function in helpers.php that can get/set session values depending on the parameters specified. Also you can access the session through the request object, as stated at:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session